recordId value is null
I have following case:
I have simple screen flow, where I want to have rich text input from user, which will be used as a body text for email. So I created LWC and Apex Controller additionally. From flow I pass the recordId to LWC, and then from LWC I pass the recordId variable to Apex class.
The problem is, that the passed recordId is in the same code both null and not null value.
For example, SOQL which you can see below, returns record to HTML component what means that the recordId has a value. But if I do system debug, IF statement or nested SOQL in IF, then I have error that recordId is null. What more interest, when I copied same code to totally different org... then everything was working fine. I have no idea, what can cause an error, can anyone help?
Controller cls:
    public with sharing class emailBodyController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string getBody(String recordId){
        try {

            system.debug('recId ' + recordId);
            Task taskRec = [SELECT Id, Subject FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :recordId OR WhoId = :recordId LIMIT 1];
            System.debug('recordId from Apex: ' + recordId);
            String bodyText = taskRec.Subject + ' ' + ' </br> ' + taskRec.Id;
            return bodyText;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

LWC Js:
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getBody from '@salesforce/apex/emailBodyController.getBody';

export default class EmailBody extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api bodyText = '';


    handleChange(event) {
        this.bodyText = event.target.value;
    }
   
    @wire(getBody, { recordId: '$recordId' }) getBody;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.getEmailBody();
    }

    getEmailBody() {
        getBody({recordId: this.recordId})
            .then((result) => {
                this.bodyText = result
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
    
    get queryResult() {
        console.log(this.bodyText);
        return this.bodyText;
    }
}

LWC meta:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property
                name="recordId"
                type="String"
                label="Record Id"
                default="{!recordId}"/>
                <property
                    name="bodyText"
                    type="String"
                    role="outputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

LWC HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-input-rich-text value={bodyText} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input-rich-text>
     <h1>{recordId}</h1>
    <h1>{queryResult}</h1>
</template>




You have both a @wire property and an imperative call to getBody. You should use one or the other. If you want to use the @wire service, you don't need to call getEmailBody in connectedCallback. The @wire service will automatically react to changes in recordId and fetch the data.
Make sure that the recordId is populated when the apex method is called from LWC.

Thanks :) You're right I forgot to comment one method. I changed it and fixed recordId variable in Flow, and now it's working.
